# What makes HTML element animate on click event without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

My question may be stupid but please I need an explanation. I found both html and CSS code to implement ON and OFF switcher but I really don't understand how the label animate is possible  without javaScript using a click event.

can someone explain to me the trick in this code. 
I have never seen this before

HTML:

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
    <style>
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 109px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in;
}
.onoffswitch-label:before {
    content: "OFF";
    display: block; width: 16px; margin: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 91px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 5px;
    padding:5px;
    width:30px;
    text-align:center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label {
    background-color: #00CED1;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label, .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label:before {
   border-color: #00CED1;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label:before {
    right: 0px; 
    content: "ON";
    padding:5px;
    width:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I know you can smoothly use transition property on element but what am amaze here is the click event in particular

Comment: .onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}  - set display: block, and you will see what triggers animation (i think, i might be wrong) :)

Comment: setting the checkbox display to block only make the display visible to user but I can see the checkbox gets checked and uncheked on click event.. meanwhile there is no javaScript code attached to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a `label` element is clicked, it activates its labelled element. In this case the labelled element is a checkbox.

This causes the checkbox to toggle its `checked` *property* (not attribute*).

The `:checked` pseudo-selector will match `input[type="checkbox"]` or `input[type="radio"]` elements that have their `checked` property in the `true` state.

The change in the `:checked` status allows the new CSS properties to be applied to the `label` because the entire selector chain subsequently matches (or no longer matches, depending on whether the checkbox is now checked or unchecked).

The CSS `transition` rule then animates the changed properties from one state to the other.

---

Here's a simple demo of a form that can be used to test the functionality of labels on various different field types. Note that the submit button won't work due to the form being in a sandboxed `<iframe>`.

```html
<form action="http://example.com" target="_blank" method="get">
  <p>
    <label for="text">text</label>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
  </p>
  
  <p>
    <label for="select">select</label>
    <select name="select" id="select">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  
  <p>
    <label for="textarea">textarea</label>
    <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </p>
  
  <p>
    <label for="checkbox">checkbox</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="checked">
  </p>
  
  <fieldset>
    <legend>radio buttons</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="radio-1">radio 1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-1" value="1">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="radio-2">radio 2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-2" value="2">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <p>
    <label for="reset">reset</label>
    <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="button">button</label>
    <button id="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

<sub>* so why is it important that the property is changed but not the attribute? When you use a reset button (`input[type="reset"]`, or `button[type="reset"]`), the form will be reset to whatever the values of the HTML attributes (or `innerHTML` for `<textarea>`) are for each field. You can test this by using JavaScript to modify the `value` attribute of a text field and then resetting the form to see that no change happens.</sub>

Comment: wow wow wow!!!... very helpful....now i get important of the "for" attribute on a label...In the above code I can see the "for" attribute has a value of the checkbox id="myonoffswitch". WOW!!

Comment: I feel like am in a class...very helpful and simplified explanation. Thank you @zzzzBov

Comment: @jamesOduro, if you find this sort of thing interesting, I highly recommend reading the actual [HTML5 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html). It's well written with lots of examples and isn't particularly difficult to read. Skip directly to the [elements of HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#semantics) and you'll learn a lot about what features the browser gives you for free by default with no JS necessary.